# Python: problem for make a Poll of favorite genres app

Tags: python

I wrote this code:

```
num = int(input())
lst = []
Horror = Romance = Comedy = History = Adventure = Action = []

for i in list(range(num)):
    str = input()
    #lst.append(str)
    word = str.split()
    for i in word[1:]:
        if i == "Horror":
            Horror.append(word[0])
        if i == "Romance":
            Romance.append(word[0])
        if i == "Comedy":
            Comedy.append(word[0])
        if i == "History":
            History.append(word[0])
        if i == "Adventure":
            Adventure.append(word[0])
        if i == "Action":
            Action.append(word[0])
        print(i)

for i in [Horror, Romance, Comedy, History , Adventure , Action]:
    print(len(i))
```

my problem is all outputs in 12!
i want with this input :

```
4
hossein Horror Romance Comedy
mohsen Horror Action Comedy
mina Adventure Action History
sajjad Romance History Action
```

Get this output:

```
Action : 3
Comedy : 2
History : 2
Horror : 2
Romance : 2
Adventure : 1
```

help me!

...................................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This here is the problem

```
Horror = Romance = Comedy = History = Adventure = Action = []
```

You are pointing to the same array every time.

You can easily verify this via:

```
a = b = []
a.append(1)
print(b) -> prints [1]

c, d = [], []
c.append(1)
print(d) -> prints []
```

However, Python has a great built-in object called dictionaries which is ideal here.

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = defaultdict(list)
a["Action"].append("hossein")
print(len(a["Action"]))
```

Here I am using [defaultdict](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/defaultdict-in-python/), which will automatically add a new list when there is no value assigned already.

Comment: thanks , my problem solved